# Query arbitray data with regex and wildcards

Tags: regex, performance, mongodb

Given this data structure

```
{
    _id: ...,
    data: [
        {key: 'articles.0.photos.0.category', value: '...'},
        {key: 'articles.0.photos.1.category', value: '...'},
        ...
    ]
}
```

... I want to query by key and value, e.g.

```
key == 'articles.0.photos.0.category' && value == 'something'
```

whereas key and value are completely arbitrary, hence the key-value schema to be able to create an index on both. The numbers in the key represent an index in an array.

In case the query looks only for the logical meaning, not the position within the array, I would need to search by regex, e.g.

```
^articles\.\d+\.photos\.\d+\.caption
```

Is this a formula for catastrophic performance or can this work in bigger data sets? Is there a better solution to index and query arbitrary data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running some tests straight on the db, I came to the conclusion that using above regexes works quite well for my scenario. On a sample set of 200k documents with a nested array of 100 key-value-objects, full index scans went up from 0.001ms for a string-match to 0.004ms for a regex-match on average. That's good enough. When not using an index, query times range from 5s to 20s.